# Facebook Facepile - Get the number of friends in the list

Tags: facebook, plugins, facebook-like

I have a page with the facepile plugin working. What I want, is to get the number of friends being displayed to each user. If it's empty (zero friends), I want to show an image. If there are more than 10 friends, I want to show a different graphic. Is this possible? I've tried using jQuery to get this number (after the iframe loads):

```
var friendsCount = $("li.uiFacepileItem").length;
```

But that isn't working... Any other ideas?

Answer (score 0):

No, it is impossible to get that information strictly from the facepile plugin.  However, you might find a way of getting a user's friends using the Graph API (https://developers.facebook.com/docs/).